# Twilio sms is not working on website hosting account

Tags: twilio-php

I am using Twilio PHP-API, I uploaded files on the server here is the link 
https://junkraider.com/twilio/send.php 
When you click on this link you will see the "`HTTP error 500`". 
Please check, `send.php` file. I have attached the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpF1L.png)

Comment: Enable the server to display errors/warnings before running the script, as there could be multiple reasons causing this issue.

Comment: So how to identify the issues? In fact i downloaded files from the Twilio .

Comment: Identify your web server first(apache/nginx) etc, and then enable server errors and warnings, this will help you to inch closer to the issue.

Comment: I got this error

Comment: getting the same, did you solved it?